# .Net string validation fails

Tags: c#, .net, string, validation

Net application that accesses Peachtree 2012 using the SDK. The application runs in all systems except in one where it throws an exception.

It was tested on:

1. **Windows 10** .Net Framework 4.5
2. **Windows 7** .Net Framework 3.5
3. **Windows 8** .Net Framework 4.5

Fails on **Windows 10 .Net Framework 4.5**

The Peachtree version is the same on all systems(it was installed using the same DVD).

The error is the following: "**Sage.SBD.ACS.Framework.DataTypes.ValidationException:** The string entered is too long. It must not be longer than 15 characters."

In order to connect to Peachtree I have to pass an App Id that is 312 characters long and is stored on a **String** parameter. When the app logic enters the part where that string is needed then the exception is thrown.

The exception is thrown at a method that has the following signature:

```
protected internal void ValidateForPropertySet(string propertyName, object value)
```

And the error is about string length, so, is there any difference between those types or it can be that there is a conflict between a COM and a .Net dll, what can be happening ???

Other fact is that the app works on 32 and 64 bit systems without any issue, this is the only one that fails.